# Can we have the spoiler text show on click too?

Tags: feature-request, iphone, spoilers

On my iPhone, in order to view spoiler text, I have to double click it, copy it, and paste it into a note or something similar.

Could we make it show on click since on that device there is no such thing as a mouse over?

> Please?

Comment: Maybe adding a pseudo anchor in the HTML and `a:active` in the CSS would be enough?

Comment: Or maybe just adding a link "show spoiler" before/after each spoiler block.