# Site-Wide: Opting out of hiding the spoiler text

Tags: feature-request, spoilers

My friends and I over at SciFi Beta, have been noticing a few problems. The first is: The spoiler tag is used almost in every other question (or in an answer) and two:

> I have to constantly reposition the mouse, when I'd like to quickly read the question.

So I was suggestion a site wide (not exchange wide) setting that disables the hiding of a spoiler. I wouldn't mind having to click on the spoiler text to enable the "show spoiler" feature.

Btw, I'm lazy so the full question is here: [Opting out of hiding spoiler markdown content.](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/543/opting-out-of-hiding-spoiler-markdown-content)

Comment: Click to show is [already an existing feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80867/can-we-have-the-spoiler-text-show-on-click-too) on its own, so yours is probably best centered on just the preference. That said, if it's used to the point of being problematic, it may be wise to revisit the frequency of its usage on that site.

Comment: Arg.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/which-meta-am-i-supposed-to-post-on/89232#89232

Comment: I'm talking about a site wide setting

Comment: If it's site-wide, then isn't @Rebecca's ARGing even more appropriate?

Comment: Why don't we just get rid of spoiler markup since everything is a spoiler to someone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The odds of getting a site-wide setting are pretty low, but you can use a userscript to unhide spoilers. I do it with:

```
function with_jquery(f) {                                                                                                                                      
    var script = document.createElement("script");                                                                                                             
    script.type = "text/javascript";                                                                                                                           
    script.textContent = "(" + f.toString() + ")(jQuery)";                                                                                                     
    document.body.appendChild(script);                                                                                                                         
};                                                                                                                                                             

with_jquery(function($) {                                                                                                                                      
    $('.spoiler').removeClass('spoiler').css('background-color', '#fbb');                                                                                      
});
```

The result is:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Darn, I was going to create the user Script. Drat!

Comment: PS, userscripts are new to me, how do I use them? Install them, or whatever?

Comment: @Justin I put it on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/103066); there's an Install button. You need to be using a browser that supports them (Firefox with Greasemonkey, or Chrome)

Comment: Could you put it up on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: @Gilles, does StackApps have a install into site function?

Answer (score 3):

The spoiler tag is just a bit of CSS.  I believe all modern browsers allow use of a user style sheet (and this doesn't require installing any sort of extension to run user scripts).  So all you need to do is add a rule that overrides the CSS in your user style sheet, and you're done.

(I don't think user style sheets can be site-specific, so this would change *any site* that uses the "spoiler" CSS class.  If that does have an impact, then IMO a better feature request would be to have SE change the class to something like "stackexchange-spoiler").

For example, in Safari, go to *Preferences*, then *Advanced*, then select the stylesheet.

Your stylesheet only needs to contain something like this:

```
.spoiler { color: #444 !important; }
```

444 is the colour that you get when hovering - you could make it something else if you wanted spoilers to stand out in some way, or add other markup like a background colour (e.g. so you avoid referencing them in answers!).

Answer (score 2):

I've created the [StackApps entry](https://stackapps.com/q/2404/301) for the UserScript and a Safari Extension.